# How to speedup write.xlsx process of excel in R

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, tidyverse, xlsx

I am in need of writing my output to an excel file in `R`. The `t_content` has around **401104 rows** and **200 columns**.

```
write.xlsx(t_content, paste0("../output/",'Content.xlsx'),
           col.names = T, append = TRUE)
```

This command takes a very long time to complete the task. Any other alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try `write_xlsx()` from the `writexl` package.

```
writexl::write_xlsx(t_content, paste0("../output/",'Content.xlsx'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table::fwrite` command is very fast, and can show you a progress bar, but it gives you a .csv file which can then be used with excel.